# Adding files to ZIP file

Tags: java, zip, directory, fileinputstream, zipoutputstream

I am trying to add some files to a ZIP file, it creates the file but does not add anything into it.
Code 1:

```
String fulldate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "-" + min;

File dateFolder = new File("F:\\" + compname + "\\" + fulldate);
dateFolder.mkdir();

String zipName = "F:\\" + compname + "\\" + fulldate + "\\" + fulldate + ".zip";

zipFolder(tobackup, zipName);
```

My function:

```
public static void zipFolder(File folder, String name) throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[18024];

    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(folder);

    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));

    int len;

    while((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    out.closeEntry();
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

**Edit:** I found the problem, it was just having trouble writing files from the C:\ drive into a ZIP in the F:\ drive

Comment: If you want to iterate over the files in the given folder, use the [`listFiles()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) of your `File`-object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't zip folders, only files. To zip folders, you have to add all the subfiles manually. I wrote this class that does the job. You can have it for free :)

The usage would be this:

```
List<File> sources = new ArrayList<File>();
sources.add(tobackup);
Packager.packZip(new File(zipName), sources);
```

Here is the class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Packager
{
    public static void packZip(File output, List<File> sources) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Packaging to " + output.getName());
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
        zipOut.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

        for (File source : sources)
        {
            if (source.isDirectory())
            {
                zipDir(zipOut, "", source);
            } else
            {
                zipFile(zipOut, "", source);
            }
        }
        zipOut.flush();
        zipOut.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static String buildPath(String path, String file)
    {
        if (path == null || path.isEmpty())
        {
            return file;
        } else
        {
            return path + "/" + file;
        }
    }

    private static void zipDir(ZipOutputStream zos, String path, File dir) throws IOException
    {
        if (!dir.canRead())
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot read " + dir.getCanonicalPath() + " (maybe because of permissions)");
            return;
        }

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        path = buildPath(path, dir.getName());
        System.out.println("Adding Directory " + path);

        for (File source : files)
        {
            if (source.isDirectory())
            {
                zipDir(zos, path, source);
            } else
            {
                zipFile(zos, path, source);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Leaving Directory " + path);
    }

    private static void zipFile(ZipOutputStream zos, String path, File file) throws IOException
    {
        if (!file.canRead())
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot read " + file.getCanonicalPath() + " (maybe because of permissions)");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Compressing " + file.getName());
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(buildPath(path, file.getName())));

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4092];
        int byteCount = 0;
        while ((byteCount = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            System.out.print('.');
            System.out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println();

        fis.close();
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

**EDIT**: To check if the program is still busy, you can add the three lines I marked with a (*)

**EDIT 2**: Try the new code. On my platform, it runs correct (OS X). I'm not sure but, there might be some limited read permissions for files in Windows in AppData.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see how it goes! EDIT: It looked good, it DID compress it (:D), but it's apparently invalid. Error:
    The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'F:\David-PC\2012-03-11-25\2012-03-11-25.zip' is invalid.

Comment: Wait - Hmm, weird. It automatically terminated itself for no reason. "Done." diddn't appear.

Comment: @cheese5505: Make sure that you give the program the needed time. Compression takes some time. Make sure the application is terminated before you try to open the zip. You could add a `System.out.print(".");` in the compression loop, to see if the program is still busy or not.

Comment: Well, I did. I exported it and ran it through CMD, but it stops suddenly. Is there a time limit? Here's the last data it sends:
Leaving Directory David/AppData/Local/Apple Computer/QuickTime
Adding Directory David/AppData/Local/Apple Computer/WebKit
Leaving Directory David/AppData/Local/Apple Computer/WebKit
Leaving Directory David/AppData/Local/Apple Computer
Adding Directory David/AppData/Local/Application Data

C:\Users\David\Desktop>

Comment: Still stopped, but it went alot further.

Comment: You'd think if java was going to provide a zip api, there would be a method like the one you just wrote. Nice work.

Comment: So you mean that to add an entry to an existing zip, you need to create a new file with the original zipped content, then add the new entry to it? Sounds inefficient but then I guess it's unavoidable since zip format is at the end of the file...

Answer (score 2):

See also [ZeroTurnaround's Zip library](http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/zeroturnaround-releases-yazlj-yet-another-zip-library-for-java/). It has such features as (citation):

- pack and unpack directories recursively
- iterate through ZIP entries

Comment: it wasn't broken 9 years ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another way using Java 7 NIO [FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html). It uses the fact that JAR files are actually ZIP:

```
static public void addToZip(Path zip, Path file) throws IOException {
    Map<String,String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "false"); // We don't create the file but modify it
    
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:"+zip.toString());
    try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
        Path f = zipfs.getPath(file.getFileName().toString());
        Files.copy(file, f, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile!

Comment: @Yahya what exactly doesn't compile? It does compile on my computer...