# The creation of HTML in a .war file using Java

Tags: java, html, jboss, war

I am trying to create a HTML file dynamically inside a `.war` file deployed in the JBoss server.

It doesn't allow me to create. Can someone help me out to create a HTML file inside a deployed `.war` file in Java?

Comment: Please describe what have you tried to update this file.

Comment: Why do you need the html file to be inside WAR?

Answer (score 1):

In that case the *war* file should be deployed as exploded. Use

```
String jbossHome = System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME");
```

to access to the server deployment.

Then you need a file separator

```
String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Then construct the path to the deployment root. Assume you have *default*

```
String deployRootPath = jbossHome + separator + "server" + separator + "default" + separator + "deploy" + separator;
File dir = new File(deployRootPath + "mywebapp.war");
if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
   File myHtmlFile = new File(dir+separator+"myhtmlfile.html"); 
   myHtmlFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Hi Roman.. i need to create a html file inside the .war file using java... how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

A WAR file is a simple ZIP file. I don't know if there is a way to "mount" a zip file and access it like a file system but you could definitely unzip the WAR file, add you file and zip it again.

[Adding files to zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103861/adding-files-to-zip-file)

Answer (score 0):

WAR is somewhat a ZIP file renamed. Uncompress add file. Rezip. I guess some library will be there to allow us to add files without completely unzipping. Just google for that.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, A .war file is just a .zip file.

I'm not going to go into how your container (JBOSS) will react when you modify the contents of a war file (probably reload your webapp automatically by default?) but you can treat the .war as any other .zip except with a different file extension.

see the [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java) about how to work with zip files in java if that's what you need to do.