# Create a Zip File in Memory

Tags: java, memory, zip, inputstream

I'm trying to zip a file (for example foo.csv) and upload it to a server.  I have a working version which creates a local copy and then deletes the local copy.  How would I zip a file so I could send it without writing to the hard drive and do it purely in memory?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use [**ByteArrayOutputStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) with [**ZipOutputStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) to accomplish the task.

you can use [**ZipEntry**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) to specify the files
to be included into the zip file.

Here is an example of using the above classes,

```
String s = "hello world";

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try(ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {

  /* File is not on the disk, test.txt indicates
     only the file name to be put into the zip */
  ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("test.txt"); 

  zos.putNextEntry(entry);
  zos.write(s.getBytes());
  zos.closeEntry();

  /* use more Entries to add more files
     and use closeEntry() to close each file entry */

} catch(IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

now `baos` contains your zip file as a `stream`

Comment: Make sure you call the close()-method in a finally block, or better: use the Automatic Resource Management of Java 7.

Comment: @Puce : I intended to show only a snippet but after your comment i felt that adding a more structured code would be good. Thanks for the comment.. :)

Comment: @BlackPanther could you elaborate more/ show a detailed version for if the origin file exists in a local directory.

Comment: @SleepDeprivedBulbasaur : [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103861/adding-files-to-zip-file/10103963#10103963) link can help you on that.

Comment: Check this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974354/creating-zip-file-in-memory-out-of-byte-zip-file-is-allways-corrupted). Remember to close the ZipOutputStream before invoking `getBytes` on ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: @hencrice and posterity, be aware that the example in that link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974354/creating-zip-file-in-memory-out-of-byte-zip-file-is-allways-corrupted) doesn't work in Java 7 or 8. They didn't add the ability to declare resource variables outside the try block until Java 9. The example in this post will work for Java 7/8 folks.

Comment: This is a very good example and I admire it. Also I can recommend just a simple addition - set appropriate encoding when use those example. try(ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) and zos.write(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Answer (score 4):

As the NIO.2 API, which was introduce in Java SE 7, supports custom file systems you could try to combine an in-memory filesystem like https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem and the Zip file system provided by Oracle.

Note: I've written some utility classes to work with the Zip file system.

The library is Open Source and it might help to get you started.

Here is the tutorial: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/0.4/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

You can download the library from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.4/

Or with Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.4</version>   
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

[nifi MergeContent contain compressZip code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/ea9b0db2f620526c8dd0db595cf8b44c3ef835be/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/MergeContent.java)

[commons-io](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io)

```
public byte[] compressZip(ByteArrayOutputStream baos,String entryName) throws IOException {
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream zipBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         final java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(zipBaos)) {
        final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
        zipEntry.setSize(baos.size());
        out.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), out);
        out.closeEntry();
        out.finish();
        out.flush();
        return zipBaos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```