# Can't write file to zip

Tags: java, file, zip

I try to put some file `fileNamePath` in zip archive (arguments are D:\text.txt D:\archive.zip):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length==0) return;

    String fileNamePath = args[0];
    String zipPath = args[1];

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipPath);
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileNamePath));

    File file = new File(fileNamePath);
    Files.copy(file.toPath(),zipOutputStream);

    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    zipOutputStream.close();

}
```

Archive is created but i don't see any file in it. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding files to ZIP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103861/adding-files-to-zip-file)

Comment: You don't see any file in it ? When I ran above code with same arguments It created a zip file with folder D: inside it and the text.txt was placed.

Comment: hmm, this kinda funny. when i extracted the archive file apeared. but it wasn't seen when i double-click on zip. i'm using win7

Answer (score -1):

That code is working perfectly:

**zip.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class zip
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length==0) return;

    String fileNamePath = args[0];
    String zipPath = args[1];

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipPath);
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileNamePath));

    File file = new File(fileNamePath);
    Files.copy(file.toPath(),zipOutputStream);

    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
    zipOutputStream.close();

}
}
```

I have compiled it under Debian 9 Stretch, OpenJDK 8

I have then created a sample txt file:

**hello.txt**

```
Hello World
```

I then compiled it:

```
javac zip.java
```

And finally run it:

```
java zip hello.txt hello.zip
```

I extract the .zip and open up hello.txt, returning `Hello World`

May it be that you have no **permissions** to `read/write` `D:\`?

Comment: i do have all permissions